# Custom object following mouse cursor not visible when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouse

I am trying to add a custom object following the mouse, I want to do that by changing the translate property and assigning x and y values to it. Everything is working fine, when the page is loaded the object is showing up when it is in the first frame and moving throughout the first frame, but when I scroll down, the transform property changed, but the custom object is not showing up, its lost somewhere, but when I scroll back to the top it suddenly appears as its only acting to when the page it on the top most

I am using position fixed because I want the cursor to stay where it is when the page is scrolling and when the scrolling stopes / the mouse started to move, I want to make the object start from there

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  document.querySelector('.mover').style.transform = `translate(${event.pageX}px, ${event.pageY}px)`
  
});
```

```css
.mover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -8px;
  top: -6px;
  transition-duration: .15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

html {
  cursor: none;
}

body {
  background: #F5F9FF;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mover">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12 ,2Z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) to `event.pageY`

Comment: @jcubic, Can you please show an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `client` instead of `page`

> The clientX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the horizontal coordinate within the application's viewport at which the event occurred (as opposed to the coordinate within the page).
>
> For example, clicking on the left edge of the viewport will always result in a mouse event with a clientX value of 0, regardless of whether the page is scrolled horizontally. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)</sup>

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  document.querySelector('.mover').style.transform = `translate(${event.clientX}px, ${event.clientY}px)`
  
});
```

```css
.mover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -8px;
  top: -6px;
  transition-duration: .15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

html {
  cursor: none;
}

body {
  background: #F5F9FF;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mover">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12 ,2Z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scrollTop property to get the position of the scroll bar and correct the position of the element.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  const style = document.querySelector('.mover').style;
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const x = event.pageX;
  const y = event.pageY;
  style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y - scrollTop}px)`
  
});
```

```css
.mover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -8px;
  top: -6px;
  transition-duration: .15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

html {
  cursor: none;
}

body {
  background: #F5F9FF;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mover">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12 ,2Z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Note that depending on the browser the scrolled element can be `body` or `html` so it's safe to check:

which of those two is chaning:

```js
document.documentElement.scrollTop
document.body.scrollTop
```